# Entity Framework without creating .edmx

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

Hi is Entity Framework 4 really need to generate .edmx or not ?

Thanks in Regards

Comment: What did edmx ever do to you>?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can use the Code First approach:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467

Comment: See also this series of 10 tutorials: http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1):

No Version 4.1 supports "Code First Development". Means you can define your Db by annotating your entities or using a Fluent API.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a nice set of articles](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/code-first-entity-framework-4-1-videos-and-articles-on-msdn/) to help get you familar with Entity Framework Code First.

Just a few nice to knows for you also:

The latest version of Entity Framework 4.1 comes with Code First (use to be separate).

With the latest MVC3 tools update, the latest version of Entity Framework is included as part of the MVC3 template.  Makes it a tad faster for getting going.

You can install the latest Entity Framework 4.1 with NuGet using `install-package EntityFramework`.